# How to call Swift functions of type Any with args of type [Any]

Tags: python, swift, compilation, compiler-construction, virtual-machine

I am currently in the process of implementing [this blog post about vms and compilers in Python](https://bernsteinbear.com/blog/bytecode-interpreters/) in Swift. I have run into a problem here:

I have a function in an `Any`. I have its arguments in `[Any]`. I want to call this function without knowing what arguments it is. In the Python post, since Python is dynamic it is simple but in Swift I assume this is not possible. Do you have any ways of implementing it?

```
let numberOfArgs: Int = try intify(instruction.arg)
let arguments: [Any] = (0 ..< numberOfArgs).compactMap { _ in
    return (stack.pop() as? Instruction)?.arg
}
let function: Any = try popVal(&stack)
```

`function` is a Swift closure. eg `(Int, Int) -> Int`, `(String, (Bool, Date) -> Date) -> Float`

In conclusion, I want to call `function` with `arguments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to wrap your functions in a closure of type `([Any]) -> Any`.  Then in the closure, unpack the arguments, downcast them to the right types and call the function.  Finally, cast the result as `Any`:

```
func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

func mult(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
    return a * b
}

var functions = [Any]()
var inputs = [[Any]]()

let f: ([Any]) -> Any = { arr in
    return add(a: arr[0] as! Int, b: arr[1] as! Int) as Any
}

functions.append(f)
inputs.append([3, 5])

let g: ([Any]) -> Any = { arr in
    return mult(a: arr[0] as! Double, b: arr[1] as! Double) as Any
}

functions.append(g)
inputs.append([6.0, 7.0])

// Each time through the loop, get one function stored as Any and
// one array of inputs with type [Any]
for (function, input) in zip(functions, inputs) {
    // Downcast function from Any to ([Any]) -> Any
    let f = function as! ([Any]) -> Any

    // Call the function
    print(f(input))
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 8
> 42.0
> ```

Comment: That is actually [what I did](https://github.com/SafelySwift/BytecodeVM/blob/master/Source/VM.swift). I wanted a better Swifty way, but I guess this is my only option. > NOTE: I did the same thing except used `([Any]) throws -> Any`